# No automatic read by the narrator when ARIA selected/pressed property changes

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria

I want the following to be read as "Selected" or "Unselected" when using the accesability narrator. Here's my approach

```
<button id="toggleButton" type="button" aria-pressed="false" aria-roledescription="button" onclick="toggleButtonState()">
     Click Me
</button>
```

the script

```
function toggleButtonState() {
    const toggleButton = document.getElementById('toggleButton');
    const isButtonSelected = toggleButton.getAttribute('aria-pressed') === 'true';

    toggleButton.setAttribute('aria-pressed', !isButtonSelected); 
}
```

I have 2 issues:

- The first one is that with **aria-pressed**, the narrator reads it as 'button on/off'. I tried using **aria-selected**, but the narrator doesn't pick up anything.
- The second issue is that the narrator should read it every time it is clicked, right? Since the ARIA property is changed. However, it doesn't. I know that if you press CapsLock+Tab, the narrator reads the state of the element again, but I want to know if there is an automatic read.

Note: There can't be any appended text like selected or unselected since this will cause localization issues.

Comment: Have you tried other screen readers such as JAWS or NVDA to rule out that it's not a Narrator bug?